# Low LSTM Accuracy in Speech Recognition

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, lstm, speech-recognition, recurrent-neural-network

> Hello everyone, I am applying LSTM to speech emotion recognition. I have performed feature extraction using MFCC, resulting in a matrix of dimensions 60,575 × 39. I subsequently transformed this matrix into a cell array named "AllCellTrain" with dimensions 280 × 1, containing signals of varying sizes, as illustrated in the image below. I then utilized "AllCellTrain" as input for the trainNetwork function, along with the labels YCA, network layers, and training options. However, I encountered a significant issue with accuracy, achieving only around 20%. I'm unsure where I may have made a mistake. Could someone please offer some assistance?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5WHj.png)

```
num_hidden_units = 1024;
layers = [
sequenceInputLayer(num_features)
lstmLayer(num_hidden_units, 'OutputMode', 'last')
fullyConnectedLayer(num_classes)
softmaxLayer
classificationLayer];
% Specify the training options
max_epochs = 36;
mini_batch_size = 28;
initial_learning_rate = 0.001;
options = trainingOptions('adam', ...
'MaxEpochs', max_epochs, ...
'MiniBatchSize', mini_batch_size, ...
'InitialLearnRate', initial_learning_rate, ...
'SequenceLength','shortest', ...
'Shuffle','every-epoch',...
'ExecutionEnvironment','gpu', ...
'Verbose', false, ...
'Plots','training-progress');
net = trainNetwork(AllCellTrain, YCA, layers, options);
predicted_labels = classify(net, AllCellTest,'ExecutionEnvironment','gpu');
acc = mean(predicted_labels == YCT)``
```

[AllTrainCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cELOj.png)

[training_progress.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHvcH.png)

Comment: Do you have graphs or measures of your loss reduction over the epochs?

Comment: @KathyReid Hello, I have added above, training progress, thanks for your help!

Comment: @KathyReid I uploded the graph!

Comment: Your training progress image shows you achieving nearly 100% accuracy after 350 iterations of training the model. When you say that your accuracy is only around 20%, are you referring to using the model on data that is unseen by the model - so when you're using the model for inference? If this is the case, then I think there may be an issue with the _test_ set that your model is using to test the accuracy of predictions. How closely does the test set mirror the data that you are going to be predicting on?